# how to parse through complex soap objects in Android

Tags: android, web-services, soap, ksoap2

Hello Friends i am using soap web services very first time in my code.
but i am not getting how to handle nested soap objects.
this is my code

```
private final String URL = "http://192.168.0.20/BookingEngineService/HotelBookingService.asmx";
    private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/AndroidTestRequest";
    private final String METHOD_NAME = "AndroidTestRequest";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("User", "abcd@xyz.com");
        request.addProperty("Password", "abcd@123");
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.headerOut = new Element[1];
        envelope.headerOut[0] = buildAuthHeader();
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            Log.i("myAppEnvelope", envelope.toString());

            SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

        // here i am trying to get values from response which is soap object 

            for (int i = 0; i < response.getPropertyCount(); i++) {

                SoapObject con = (SoapObject) response.getProperty(i);

                Log.e("Continent", con.toString());
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

i am getting soap object as a response and which is very complex so i am not getting how to parse it. [this is my response](http://pastie.org/7708025)  this is very small part of my response.

I am not getting how to get values from SoapObject -> Properties -> elementData -> value-> property -> elementData and so on ... its too complex please help me.

Comment: Hi, I am facing a similar problem, so were you able convert the `SoapObject` to `InputStream`? I have used methods from the `SoapObject` class to parse the `SoapObject` response, but it takes a bit too long to parse it. I'd like to convert the `SoapObject` to `InputStream` and use `XMLPullParser`, but don't know how. Any suggestion will be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert soap object to a string. Check the example code bellow
Eg:

```
     final  SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
     final String str = response.toString();
```

Comment: thanks for reply but its not possible to convert the response into String because its too heavy and if i try to store it into String it will give me out of memory exception.

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple XML parsing. Go through the [link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html) for more details.

You can get the response as input stream and convert that into string and using that string, you can create an XML object. Please refer the link for more information.

Comment: i know it's a simple xml but how to get this whole xml from Soap Object response ? and the link given by you is giving me 404 error unable to open. can you please tell me how to parse this xml through soap object???? n thanks for quick response

Comment: but i am getting my response in SoapObject so there i am facing the problem actually.. i am not getting how to parse through it or according to you how can i create a xml or input stram from it can you please provide some code for it.. ?

Comment: can you refer this link http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-ksoap2-android-and-parsing-output-data